# Recommendation on mocking services for long running resiliency testing?

Tags: ibm-watson

We are going to be running resiliency testing (which will generate 100's of thousands (maybe millions) of calls a day). To avoid that we are looking to mock the services while still being able to model general behavior (latency, cached results) and being able to inject bad behavior or errors.

I realize that to the client these are just classes and one can use Mockito or similar, but I don't think that scales well to that number of calls and doesn't really help with the modeling aspect.

Another option is something like WireMock but I don't see how I can inject different URLs into the SDK.

Are there any other options or approaches that might be useful for me to consider?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can the API be used over HTTP (i.e. not HTTPS)?

If so you could try running WireMock with browser proxying (bad name for forward proxying!) enabled and point your JVM/system proxy settings at that.

Comment: Hence me pointing out that browser proxying is a bad name for forward proxying. You can configure a server JVM to use a proxy server just as you can with a browser.